# Strange Border around Embedded .swf file

Tags: html, embed, flash

I am currently transitioning a site from one host to another. The original .swf files I am trying to replace but for some reason there is a strange looking border around the images. Can anyone explain why or how to fix it?

Here is the site that is currently being hosted where the header image .swf file is displayed properly:
http://www.waimeasmiles.com

This is the site under the new host where the strange border is:
http://waimeasmiles.com.192-185-7-17.secure22.win.hostgator.com/smile_gallery.asp

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird little border alright. I've glanced over the code and didn't see anything glaring. I can tell you that the "border" you're seeing is the swf's declared background color. (One black, the other white.) It's as if the swfs have a 1px offset but from what I can see nothing has changed regarding their embed or styles.

In fact, one of the only differences I noticed while scanning your code was: 
The original location's html has a closing paragraph tag at the end of the file (outside the closing body and html tags) but it seems to have been removed from the new location's html.

Errant or "catch-all" closing tags are bad, mmmk. I can't think of any reason this would affect the flash, but considering the heavily nested, difficult to read code on that page, I might try adding it back just for the sake of having tried it. ;)

Aside from that you may want to try "zeroing out" some elements in your css to see if that helps. Something like:

```
div, object {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
```